# Informatica Persistent Data Masking

Tags: informatica, masking, data-masking

I am working on Informatica Persistent Data Masking tool and I have to mask repeatable values in different tables and schemas with same masking pattern.

For example: if some name say sonal is repeating in different tables, I want to mask sonal in all tables with same masked value.

How can I do that? or which masking should I use? I have tried Key masking and similar value columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps....

1. Create individual Connections (under 'Administrator' tab of the product) for Databases which contain the Tables that have data 'Sonal'.
2. Now, navigate to Projects tab and create a new Project and Import the Metadata from all the Connections you have created (make sure you pick required tables from each of those Connection)
3. Under 'Policies' page, create a "New Masking Rule" by choosing Masking Type as 'Substitution' (from 'Standard' drop-menu). Click on 'Next'.
4. In the 2nd step of this Rule creation wizard, select 'Repeatable' and enter any value between 1 & 1000 as 'Seed'
5. Select any valid Dictionary (can be a Flatfile dic or a Relational dic - but this should've already been created/added under 'Administrator -> Dictionaries' page) that has Serial Number & some valid Names which can be used to mask the Names in original/Source tables.
6. Pick correct columns for 'Masked Value' & 'Serial Number Column'fields. And save the Rule.
7. Add this Rule to your Project (which has Meatadata of all the required Tables) under "Project -> Overview -> Policies" page
8. Navigate to 'Define -> Data Masking' page, select all the required columns (in this example, whichever columns contain the name 'Sonal') and mark them as Similar value columns.
9. Assign the Substitution Masking Rule (which was created with 'Repeatable' option in Step #6) to a Column. Save the changes.
10. Create a Plan by navigating to 'Execute' page. Make sure you select the correct Masking Rule. After saving this Plan, select 'Generate and Execute' from Actions menu.

Once this Plan is executed successfully, you can see the Masked values (consistent value for all the occurrences of 'Sonal') in the Target Database(s).